# Por que está tocando o som de erro do Windows ao invés do arquivo especificado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import winsound


winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/Computador/Music/Action!/som1.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Quando eu executo este *script* não é tocado o arquivo `som1.wav`, mas sim o som de erro do Windows. Por que?

Comment: Aquele ponto de exclamação "**!**" compõe a URL?

Comment: Grande chance de ser o caminho errado do arquivo. Experimente adicionar a flag `winsound.SND_NODEFAULT` - Essa flag determina que se não encontrar o arquivo, não é para por o som padrão no lugar. E certifique-se que o seu `som1.wav` não é igual o do Windows...

Comment: Deu ''Failed to play sound'' com ''winsound.SND_NODEFAULT''

Comment: Então já sabemos que o problema está no seu áudio. Poderia confirmar se a exclamação faz parte do caminho do seu arquivo?

Comment: Sim, ela faz parte

Comment: E é permitido ter esse caractere no caminho de um arquivo no Windows?

Comment: Mesmo sem o ''!'' não funcionou

Comment: Pra tirar a dúvida, ponha o som na mesma pasta da aplicação, para ver se o problema é no arquivo ou no caminho

Comment: [`winsound.SND_FILENAME`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_FILENAME): *The sound parameter is the name of a WAV file.* Não teria que utilizar esta flag?

Comment: Coloquei na mesma pasta, usei a flag 'SND_FILENAME', usei outro som com formato mp3, mas ainda toca o som do windows

Comment: Tentou fazer tudo isso com um arquivo WAV mesmo?

Comment: Sim, eu tentei com o WAV

Comment: @Tortaamolante tenta passando por variável o caminho, como nesse [exemplo](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216438/play-those-cute-little-wave-files-python)

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, o script não conseguia encontrar o arquivo e por isso tocava o som default do windows, mas mudei a flag e coloquei outro arquivo e funcionou.

Comment: Edita a resposta com a solução do problema, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema ;)

Comment: Beleza, coloquei la :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema estava na falta da flag `SND_NODEFAULT` e o diretório estava errado.

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('teste.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME | winsound.SND_PURGE | winsound.SND_NODEFAULT)
```

Testei com arquivos mp3 e não funcionou, apenas com wav

Comment: está certo - isso foi o que funcionou - o problema era apenas o caminho do arquivo e a falta do `SND_NODEFAULT`. Se a pergunta for editada pra incluir isso, deixa de ser pergunta.